# Testing whether Argument is valid or not

Tags: logic

I am to determine if argument is valid by making truth table

[image]

**ATTEMPT**

Let

W= Warning lights will come on
P= Pressure is high
R=Relief valve is clogged

Then i have premises as

W $\leftrightarrows$ P **AND** R ,where the symbol indicates bi conditional statement (1st Premise)

**Negatition** R                         (2nd Premise)

Therefore W $\leftrightarrows$  P   (Conclusion)

[image]

Now i made truth table as usual with 8 rows and written all other stuff. In first row where W,P,R are false , the premises and conclusion is coming out to be true which makes argument valid. But textbook states that it is invalid. I would like to know where i am going wrong

Thanks

Comment: As $R$ is false. "$P$ and $R$" is false too. And you get that $W$ is always false.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are trying to use a truth table here? It doesn't seem at all necessary.

Comment: @quid please check my work and let me know where is mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you want to solve your problem using the truth table.

- Firstly, here is an intuitive approach that I believe the first thing to do when you have such problems.

$$ ``\mbox{Warning lights is on}" \Longleftrightarrow ``\mbox{Pressure is high}" \wedge  \ `` \mbox{Relief valve is clogged }" $$

is equivalent to :

$$ ``\mbox{Warning lights is } \color{#C00}{off} " \Longleftrightarrow `` \mbox{Pressure is } \color{#C00}{not} \mbox{ high}" \vee  \ `` \mbox{Relief valve is } \color{#C00}{not} \mbox{ clogged }" \tag{P} $$

Now, we consider the statements $(P)$ to be true and that $``\mbox{the Relief valve is not clogged}"$, that implies that Warning lights is off ( regardless of the pressure).
So the conclusion is obviously invalid (because the pressure can be too hight and the warning still off).

- Now if  the table is required by the question, you have to add an arrow in your table that contain the truth values of

$$ \left( (W \Longleftrightarrow  R \wedge P) \wedge \lnot R \right) \Longrightarrow \left( W \Longleftrightarrow P \right) $$

Answer (score 1):

The claimed conclusion is not $W\leftrightarrow R$ as you wrote but rather it is $W\leftrightarrow P$. From the given $\neg R$ we can conclude that $P\land R$ is false and hence the equivalent $W$ is also false. If the claim *were* correct,we could infer $\neg P$, but we certainly can't.

Incidentally, your mistake in encoding the claim as $W\leftrightarrow R$ does give a valid conclusion: As seen above, $W$ is false and as both $W$ and $R$ are false, $W\leftrightarrow$ is true.

Comment: no no it was a typo. i meant P and not R

Comment: I have uploaded my work, where is mistake?

Comment: The premises i have ticked are the ones should be consistent with each other, aren't they?

Comment: In the third line the premises $\neg R$ amd $ are both true, but the conlusion is false

Comment: But i was talking about first line